# host.docker.internal not working in github action

Tags: docker, github-actions

This is my simplified jobs.

```
jobs:
  build_and_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ubuntu:latest

    services:
      rod: # Rod browser
        image: ghcr.io/go-rod/rod
        options: >-
          --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway
        ports:
          - 7317:7317

    steps:
      - name: test docker host
        run: host host.docker.internal
```

The `test docker host` step fails.

`Host host.docker.internal not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

I use that `--add-host` on local (Mac) and it works. It resolved to the host IP.

How to access the host from the docker container in GitHub action?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/go-rod/rod/actions/runs/786912323/workflow can help you.